# How to Convert Working Query into Eloquent Lumen config

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Dears,

I have this working query to retrieve token and appid information from two pgsql tables. I am trying to implement an API by using Lumen framework. How can i convert this query to eloquent statements? So its possible to configure controller section. I have tried this http://cryptic-peak-77605.herokuapp.com/ but without succes

```
SELECT token,appid FROM db.public.tokens WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM db.public.data WHERE (name,value) IN (('userName', '100'), ('domain', '1591.xpto.xyz' )) group by id having count(distinct VALUE) = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$records = YourModel::where('id', DB::select("SELECT id FROM data WHERE (name,value) IN (('userName', '100'), ('domain', '1591.xpto.xyz' )) group by id having count(distinct VALUE) = 2"))->select(['token', 'appid'])->get();
```

But looking at the above query it seems that it would be a good choice if we would proceed with a complete raw query like

```
$records = DB::select("SELECT token,appid FROM tokens WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM data WHERE (name,value) IN (('userName', '100'), ('domain', '1591.xpto.xyz' )) group by id having count(distinct VALUE) = 2);");
```